# onCallStateChanged does not change state

Tags: android, phone-state-listener

I have a problem with `onCallStateChanged()`
its not the listener or the programm itself.

Everything works fine except of one thing.
I can't jump off a call state when I'm in an `while()-Loop`.

What I am trying to do is let the LED blink when phone is ringing.

So I jump into:

```
if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state){
// Incoming call handling

        Log.d(incomingNumber, "Ring");
        ring = true;
        idle = false;

        if (mCamera == null) {
            mCamera = Camera.open();

            Parameters pLightOn = mCamera.getParameters();
            Parameters pLightOff = mCamera.getParameters();

            pLightOn.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            pLightOff.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);

            mCamera.setParameters(pLightOn);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            //##########################################
            while(ring && !idle){

                try {
                    mCamera.setParameters(pLightOff);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                    mCamera.setParameters(pLightOn);
                    Thread.sleep(30);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    idle = true;
                    pLightOff.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(RuntimeException ex){
                    idle = true;
                    pLightOff.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    String errorMessage = "Error setting camera flash status. Your device may be unsupported.";
                }
            }

            idle = true;
            ring = false;
            pLightOff.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            //##########################################                
        }
    }
```

**But the problem is that when I end the calling it does not jump off the `WHILE`.
`STATE` does not change, it stays on `RING`.
so I have endless blinking. It never comes back to `IDLE`.**

**When I remove the `while-loop` everything works fine though.**
It jumps in. Switch `LED ON`... then `OFF`... and when I end calling it returns to `IDLE`.
Just one time... but I want him to do this as long as the phone is in `RING` State.

Any idea to solve this problem..??

Answer (score 1):

It seems the thread problem. Do not program while-loop in android main thread. Just create a thread for while-loop to avoid block main thread block.